# How to remove different version of stopwords

Tags: r, quanteda

I use this way to remove stop words from text

```
dfm <- 
    tokens(df$text,
           remove_punct = TRUE, 
           remove_numbers = TRUE, 
           remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
    tokens_remove(pattern = stopwords(source = "smart")) %>%
      tokens_wordstem()
```

However in the result I found that there are stop words like this one:

```
dont
```

Is there any way to remove them without using a customized list of stopwords?

Comment: I think's pretty hard to find how to remove also spelling errors (that seems to be one of them). I think I'd preprocess my texts to remove/replace all the errors, then I remove the stopwords.

Comment: you may have a look at     fuzzywuzzyR, where you can do partial matching of texts. Will require some python modules

Comment: Are you asking how to remove a specific set of words or how to remove words like "dont" in general?

Comment: What might help is to first remove the stopwords and then remove punctuation. Instead of the other way around. This might work in case of the dont example.

Comment: The textclean or qdap package can help with this. The function `replace_contraction` replaces "don't" with "do not". You need to do this before removing any punctuation. Both packages are from the same author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say “remove them” I am assuming that you mean remove `dont` from your tokens, whereas the existing stopwords list only removes `don’t`. (Although this was not entirely clear from your question or from how some of the answers have interpreted it.) Two simple solutions exist within the **quanteda** framework.

First, you can append additional removal patterns to the `tokens_remove()` call.

Second, you could process the character vector returned by `stopwords()` to also include the versions without apostrophes.

Illustration:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.5.1

toks <- tokens("I don't know what I dont or cant know.")

# original
tokens_remove(toks, c(stopwords("en")))
## tokens from 1 document.
## text1 :
## [1] "know" "dont" "cant" "know" "."

# manual addition
tokens_remove(toks, c(stopwords("en"), "dont", "cant"))
## tokens from 1 document.
## text1 :
## [1] "know" "know" "."

# automatic addition to stopwords
tokens_remove(toks, c(
  stopwords("en"),
  stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(stopwords("en"), "'", "")
))
## tokens from 1 document.
## text1 :
## [1] "know" "know" "."
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with the `stopwords` function itself. However, you can create your own lexicon fairly easily from the "smart" lexicon and then remove the words you don't want:

`my_stopwords <- data.frame(word=stopwords(source="smart")) %>% filter(word != "dont")`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to manage it with a couple of packages and functions. It seems you're confident with `tidyverse`, so here a kind of solution.

Remember that's not a perfect way and if you have a very small amount of text (short text), I think you can manage it manually removing the errors: my solution could help if you have not idea about how many and what are the errors.

```
library(quanteda) # for your purposes
library(qdap)     # to detect errors
library(tidytext) # lovely package about tidy texts
```

Due you've not shared your data, here some fake ones:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:2),text = c("dont panic", "don't panic"), stringsAsFactors = F)
 df
  id        text
1  1  dont panic
2  2 don't panic
```

Now, first we have to remove the errors:

```
unnested <- df %>% unnest_tokens(not.found,text)         # one line per words
errors <- data.frame(check_spelling(unnested$not.found)) # check the errors, it could take time
full <- unnested %>% left_join(errors)                   # join them!
```

Here the result:

```
full 
  id not.found row word.no suggestion                                more.suggestions
1  1      dont   1       1      don't donut, don, dot, docent, donate, donuts, dopant
2  1     panic  NA    <NA>       <NA>                                            NULL
3  2     don't  NA    <NA>       <NA>                                            NULL
4  2     panic  NA    <NA>       <NA>                                            NULL
```

Now it could be easy to tidy it:

```
full <- full %>% 
       # if there is a correction, replace the wrong word with it                                                           
       mutate(word = ifelse(is.na(suggestion), not.found, suggestion)) %>%
       # select useful columns
       select(id,word) %>%
       # group them and create the texts
       group_by(id) %>%
       summarise(text = paste(word, collapse = ' '))

full 
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id text       
  <int> <chr>      
1     1 don't panic
2     2 don't panic
```

Now you're ready to do your things:

```
tokens(as.character(full$text),
       remove_punct = TRUE, 
       remove_numbers = TRUE, 
       remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_remove(pattern = stopwords(source = "smart")) %>%
  tokens_wordstem()

tokens from 2 documents.
text1 :
[1] "panic"

text2 :
[1] "panic"
```